# Is there a Django template filter that handles "...more" and when you click on it, it shows more of the text?

Tags: python, django, templates, plugins, filter

Suppose I have a huge paragraph.

I just want the top 15 words to be shown.  After than, the person clicks "more" to see the rest of the stuff.

Comment: I don't know of any such filter, but it shouldn't be all that hard to write. You want the showing of more information to be done with JavaScript, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just whipped this up, seems to do what you want, and there's no dependency on any external JS libs.

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tried this in IE, but chrome and firefox work fine.

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

import re

readmore_showscript = ''.join([
"this.parentNode.style.display='none';",
"this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('more')[0].style.display='inline';",
"return false;",
]);

@register.filter
def readmore(txt, showwords=15):
    global readmore_showscript
    words = re.split(r' ', escape(txt))

    if len(words) <= showwords:
        return txt

    # wrap the more part
    words.insert(showwords, '<span class="more" style="display:none;">')
    words.append('</span>')

    # insert the readmore part
    words.insert(showwords, '<span class="readmore">... <a href="#" onclick="')
    words.insert(showwords+1, readmore_showscript)
    words.insert(showwords+2, '">read more</a>')
    words.insert(showwords+3, '</span>')

    # Wrap with <p>
    words.insert(0, '<p>')
    words.append('</p>')

    return mark_safe(' '.join(words))

readmore.is_safe = True
```

To use it, just create a templatetags folder in your app, create the `__init__.py` file in there, and then drop this code into `readmore.py`.

Then at the top of any template where you want to use it, just add: `{% load readmore %}`

To use the filter itself:

`{{ some_long_text_var|readmore:15 }}`

The :15 tells how many words you want to show before the read more link.

If you want anything fancy like ajax loading of the full content, that's quite a bit different and would require a bit more infrastructure.

Comment: I think this is very close. You are just missing ``if len(words) > showwords`` right before you start the insertion dance (still need the <p> tag though) otherwise you add a readmore link when one isn't necessary.

Comment: Oh yes, I know :) I'd actually keep the <p> tag insertion and the mark_safe by just indenting the more and readmore part. Thanks for this, great solution!

Comment: Thx 4 this awesome Post :D

Comment: @rossipedia, hello, I am facing a problem with this custom filter. It seems to be not working with built-in filters. For example, {{post.text|safe|linebreaksbr|readmore:15}} adds the "read more" link, the filter works fine, but other built-in filters such as "safe" and "linebreaksbr" are not working now. Can you help with this? Did anyone else face this problem?

Comment: @SkGolamSaroar I'm sorry, this answer is quite old, and I haven't worked with Django in well over 8 years now. I'm afraid I'd have no idea how to debug this currently.

Answer (score 2):

> use truncatechars_html
>
> refer to : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html

```
truncatechars_html

Similar to truncatechars, except that it is aware of HTML tags. Any tags that are opened in the string and not closed before the truncation point are closed immediately after the truncation.

For example:

{{ value|truncatechars_html:9 }}
If value is "<p>Joel is a slug</p>", the output will be "<p>Joel i...</p>".

Newlines in the HTML content will be preserved.
```

Comment: This is better, updated answer even though you should change answer for truncatewords_html.

Comment: This does not solve the issue (which is to display a `more` link).

Answer (score 0):

There is [truncatewords](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatewords) filter, although you still need a JavaScript helper to do what you described.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def readmore(text, cnt=250):
    text, cnt = escape(text), int(cnt)

    if len(text) > cnt:
        first_part = text[:cnt]
        link = u'<a href="javascript:;" class="more">%s</a>' % _('read more')
        second_part = u'%s<span class="hide">%s</span>' % (link, text[cnt:])
        return mark_safe('... '.join([first_part, second_part]))
    return text

readmore.is_safe = True
```

Answer (score 0):

I  rewrote an earlier answer to be cleaner and to handle string escaping properly:

```
@register.filter(needs_autoescape=True)
@stringfilter
def read_more(s, show_words, autoescape=True):
    """Split text after so many words, inserting a "more" link at the end.

    Relies on JavaScript to react to the link being clicked and on classes
    found in Bootstrap to hide elements.
    """
    show_words = int(show_words)
    if autoescape:
        esc = conditional_escape
    else:
        esc = lambda x: x
    words = esc(s).split()

    if len(words) <= show_words:
        return s

    insertion = (
        # The see more link...
        '<span class="read-more">&hellip;'
        '    <a href="#">'
        '        <i class="fa fa-plus-square gray" title="Show All"></i>'
        '    </a>'
        '</span>'
        # The call to hide the rest...
        '<span class="more hidden">'
    )

    # wrap the more part
    words.insert(show_words, insertion)
    words.append('</span>')
    return mark_safe(' '.join(words))
```

The HTML in there assumes you're using Bootstrap and Fontawesome, but if that's not your flavor, it's easy to adapt.

For the JavaScript, assuming you're using jQuery (if you're using Bootstrap you probably are), you'll just need to add something like this:

```
$(".read-more").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this);
    t.parent().find('.more').removeClass('hidden');
    t.addClass('hidden');
});
```

Comment: Excellent! You need also: `from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter` and `from django.utils.html import conditional_escape`. Works with django 3.0