# Django slice of content

Tags: django, templates, slice

i would like to display a "... more" lable after a 100 slice to dsiplay the full comment content, can anybody help?

**template:**

```
   <div class="comment">
        {% for comment in post.comment_set.all %}
            <p>{{ comment.content| linebreaks}}</p>
            <p>{{ comment.content|slice:":100"|linebreaksbr}}
                {% if comment.content|length > 100 %}
                   ????
                {% endif %}</p>
```

Comment: You probably want to use `truncatechars_html`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html

Comment: Okay, also works but how can i make it display "...more" and to pop up the rest of the comment content?

Comment: solved

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598460/is-there-a-django-template-filter-that-handles-more-and-when-you-click-on-iT